# deleting/closing current tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

Is there any simple way to close the current tab or single tab in androids?
I don't want to do clearing all tabs and adding the required tabs?

Please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

With regards
Kavya

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, but I did not solved it with closing tabs. 
My solution was: set tab's visibility to View.GONE and tab will be invisible.

```
    TabHost tabs=getTabHost();
    tabs.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Even I did the same atlast :) Thanks.

Comment: I have one more problem. I want to put button on each tabs. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean put button on the TabWidget's buttons (tab button)?

Comment: I think it's possible, but it will be a little hard. You need rewrite TabWidget source code or extend TabWidget.

Comment: I didn't get u. can u please explain me in detail?

Comment: TabWidget's button can contain only text label and image. But you can take source code of TabWidget and change it according to your needs. Why do you want this?

Comment: for closing of tabs :) means same like a tabs of browser i wanted to implement. a button on each tab,and a listener to that button to close the tab after clicking it.